# why certain details from json are not added to the DOM using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a simple bootstrap modal where I have a movie a user can add buttons , and a user can resize, drag them as they wish and save it to json on click,

After user added a button looks like this:
[image]

When user resize and drag the button like this

[image]

When data is saved assume user added one button to the movie here is how it looks.

```
  {
  "movies": [
    {
      "title": "Ecommerce",
      "movieid": "51",
      "movie_url": "videos/mena.mp4",
      "buttons": [
        {
          "left": 289,
          "top": 95,
          "start_time": 3.84,
          "end_time": 8.2,
          "buttonid": "0",
          "height": 167,
          "width": 322
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "travel",
      "movieid": "10",
      "movie_url": "videos/whats_your.mp4",
      "buttons": [

      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is js fordisplaying these buttons

```
     for (var a = 0; a < movies.length; a++) {
                            if (videoClicked == movies[a].movieid) {
                                    for (var b = 0; b < movies[a].buttons.length; b++) {
                                            addButtonClickArea(movies[a].buttons[b].left, movies[a].buttons[b].top, movies[a].buttons[b].width, movies[a].buttons[b].height);                 
                                    }

                            }
                      }
```

Here is js to add buttons

```
   function addButtonClickArea(left, top, width, height) {
        videoClicked = $('#modalVideo').find("video").attr("movieid");
        clickarea = $("<div id='" + clickAreIncrement + "' class='clickarea' />");
        clickAreIncrement++;

        $('#modalVideo').find(".caption-content").append(clickarea);

        clickarea.draggable({
                containment: "parent",
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                        var buttonDragged = $(".clickarea").attr("id");
                        left = ui.position.left;
                        top = ui.position.top;
                        for (var a = 0; a < movies.length; a++) {
                                if (videoClicked == movies[a].movieid) {
                                        for (var b = 0; b < movies[a].buttons.length; b++) {
                                                if (buttonDragged == movies[a].buttons[b].buttonid)
                                                        movies[a].buttons[b].left = left;
                                                movies[a].buttons[b].top = top;
                                        }

                                }
                        }
                }
        });
        clickarea.resizable({
                containment: "parent",
                autoHide: true,
                handles: "all",
                stop: function (event, ui) {
                        var buttonresized = $(".clickarea").attr("id");
                        height = $(clickarea).height();

                        width = $(clickarea).width();

                        for (var a = 0; a < movies.length; a++) {
                                if (videoClicked == movies[a].movieid) {
                                        for (var b = 0; b < movies[a].buttons.length; b++) {
                                                if (buttonresized == movies[a].buttons[b].buttonid)
                                                        movies[a].buttons[b].height = height;
                                                movies[a].buttons[b].width = width;
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }

        });
}
```

Now when user save the changes he made and refresh the page

it display this

[image]

> UPDATE
>   Here is js function to add data to json

```
function addButtonToJson(left, top, start_time, end_time, width, height){
        for (var a = 0; a < movies.length; a++) {
                if (videoClicked == movies[a].movieid) {
                                movies[a].buttons.push({
                                        left: left,
                                        top: top,
                                        start_time:start_time,
                                        end_time: end_time,
                                        width: width,
                                        height: height,
                                        buttonid: clickarea.attr('id')
                                });
                        } else {
                }

        }
}
```

what am I doing wrong with my codes? any suggestion or help will be appreciated

Comment: where did you save data before refresh and how did you get them?

Comment: Hi am saving to data.json using ajax and php

Comment: Perfect, create a snippet (js + html) in order to create evidence of your issue. Thanks

Comment: I will provide a repository you can clone it and check read me , here is repo : https://github.com/throne1986/editor  make sure you have xamp or something similar for php

Comment: Thanks. Asap I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the initial position or size in `addButtonClickArea`. You just need to add:

```
clickarea.css({top: top, left: left, height: height, width: width});
```

Comment: ur The God , Thanks